# How to update user input result in while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to give the user information about the product, but how can I give it to them in case they add another product to the order?

```
import datetime

db = [
    {
        'product': 'cola',
        'price': {
            'USD': '2',
            'GEL': '6'
        },
        'amount': 20,
        'validity': '17/12/2019'
    },
    {
        'product': 'cake',
        'price': {
            'USD': '3',
            'GEL': '9'
        },
        'amount': 15,
        'validity': '17/12/2019'
    },
    {
        'product': 'tea',
        'price': {
            'USD': '1',
            'GEL': '3'
        },
        'amount': 14,
        'validity': '17/12/2019'
    },
]

amount_of_product = {}
validity_of_product = {}
prices_of_product = {}


for i in db:
    amount_of_product.update({i["product"]: i["amount"]})
    validity_of_product.update({i["product"]: i["validity"]})
    prices_of_product.update({i["product"]: i["price"]})

adLoop = True
final_price = []

while adLoop:
    user_input = input("Please enter a product name: ")
    if user_input in amount_of_product.keys() and validity_of_product.keys():
        print(f"Currently, we have {amount_of_product[user_input]} amount of {user_input} left, "
              f"which are valid through {validity_of_product[user_input]}")

    user_input_two = int(input("Please enter the amount: "))
    user_input_three = input("In which currency would you like to pay in?(GEL or USD: ").upper()
    price = prices_of_product[user_input][user_input_three]
    total = user_input_two * int(price)
    if user_input_three == "GEL":
        final_price.append(total)
        print(f"Your order is: {user_input_two} {user_input} and total price for it is: {total}₾")
    elif user_input_three == "USD":
        final_price.append(total * 3)
        print(f"Your order is: {user_input_two} {user_input} and total price for it is: {total}$")

    stop_or_order = input("Would you like to add anything else?: ")
    if stop_or_order == "yes":
        adLoop = True
    elif stop_or_order == "no":
        adLoop = False
```

so if user orders cola and cake, I want the output to look like this:
Your order is 1 cola and 1 cake and total price of it is: sum(final_price)

But every time I execute the code, the older input gets removed and I get the newer input as a result. I want to save it somewhere and show the user everything he/she ordered.

Comment: Then save it into some kind of database? could be an in-memory dictionary where the key is the username/userid and the value is the order.

Comment: you keep over writting the input so ofcourse it prints only the last entry. Use a data structure like list or something to store each item in the order

Comment: Yeah, understood. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Not part of the posted question, but wouldn't you ask for the currency before going into the loop or at the end, when you calculate the price? I doubt you need the functuonality to pay cola in USD and tea in GEL

Comment: Actually yes, this was just a code for testing. Everything will be fixed in the final one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining *user_input* inside the loop, so it gets overwritten each iteration. You could define an dict

```
user_shopping_cart = {
  'cola':0,
  'cake':0,
  'tea':0
}
```

before the while loop and update the cart as the user puts items inside,
then generate the output with data from the cart.